# Remove last character from string in sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to remove the last character from a column output in sql plus. The length of the column entries is not fixed

For e.g XYZA should output as XYZ

I've tried using the `substr()` function but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SUBSTR(ooo.CO_NAME,1,LENGTH(ooo.CO_NAME-1))
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A closing parenthesis is in the wrong place. It should be:

```
SUBSTR(ooo.CO_NAME, 1, LENGTH(ooo.CO_NAME) - 1)
```